# Automapper :- Mapping List <SourceClass> Property to List<DestinatioClass> inside a class

Tags: c#, automapper

Hi I have below structure which is same as of my DTO's returned by a backend service and I want to configure it on Automapper. I will get a List  along with data for workflow and workflowhistory . My automapper config looks like this

```
public static void Initialize()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize((config) =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<WorkFlowApi.Models.WorkFlowMaster, WorkFlow.Entities.WorkFlowMaster>().ReverseMap()
            config.CreateMap<WorkFlowApi.Models.WorkFlow, WorkFlow.Entities.WorkFlow>().ReverseMap();
            config.CreateMap<WorkFlowApi.Models.WorkFlowHistory, WorkFlow.Entities.WorkFlowHistory>().ReverseMap();

        });
    }
```

Backend service resutnrs the List with al linformation and I am trying this code .But child properties are not getting populated .

```
 var result = _service.GetWorkFlowDetails(requestId);
List<Models.WorkFlowMaster> listObj = Mapper.Map<List<WorkFlow.Entities.WorkFlowMaster>, List<Models.WorkFlowMaster>>(result);

public class WorkFlowMaster
{
    public DateTime StartedOn { get; set; }
    public string StartedBy { get; set; }
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
    public List<WorkFlow> WorkFlow { get; set; }  
    public WorkFlowMaster()
    {
        WorkFlow = new List<Models.WorkFlow>();

    }
}

public class WorkFlow
{
    public string Role { get; set; }        
    public int ApprovalStageOrder { get; set; }
    public string PersonnelNumber { get; set; }      
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public bool IsReviewer { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public List<WorkFlowHistory> WorkFlowHistory { get; set; }
    public WorkFlow()
    {
        WorkFlowHistory = new List<Models.WorkFlowHistory>();
    }
}
public class WorkFlowHistory
{
    public string Role { get; set; }       
    public int ApprovalStageOrder { get; set; }
    public string PersonnelNumber { get; set; }             
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public bool IsReviewer { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I think the mapping is only one level. I have child list mapped manually like CM<a,b>().ForMember(dest => dest.A, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.B)); if B have own mapping then it would be mapped.

Comment: Can you run `Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` to see if you get any configuration errors in AutoMapper?